The issue of loading worlds with Minecraft Folia's WorldCreate
I am using Folia and need to load a world that has already been saved to disk. However, I'm unsure which scheduler to use: EntityScheduler, GlobalRegionScheduler, RegionScheduler, or perhaps no scheduler at all
Code for loading the world:
WorldCreator worldCreator = new WorldCreator("world");
worldCreator.environment(World.Environment.NORMAL);
worldCreator.generateStructures(true);
worldCreator.type(WorldType.NORMAL);
Bukkit.createWorld(worldCreator);

The error thrown when running the code：
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'worldtp' in plugin Pluralistic v1.0.0
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[folia-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:155) ~[folia-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:1042) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R3.command.BukkitCommandWrapper.run(BukkitCommandWrapper.java:64) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at com.mojang.brigadier.context.ContextChain.runExecutable(ContextChain.java:73) ~[brigadier-1.2.9.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.commands.execution.tasks.ExecuteCommand.execute(ExecuteCommand.java:31) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at net.minecraft.commands.execution.tasks.ExecuteCommand.execute(ExecuteCommand.java:19) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at net.minecraft.commands.execution.UnboundEntryAction.lambda$bind$0(UnboundEntryAction.java:8) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at net.minecraft.commands.execution.CommandQueueEntry.execute(CommandQueueEntry.java:5) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at net.minecraft.commands.execution.ExecutionContext.runCommandQueue(ExecutionContext.java:103) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at net.minecraft.commands.Commands.executeCommandInContext(Commands.java:434) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at net.minecraft.commands.Commands.performCommand(Commands.java:336) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at net.minecraft.commands.Commands.performCommand(Commands.java:323) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.performChatCommand(ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.java:2285) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.lambda$handleChatCommand$14(ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.java:2245) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at io.papermc.paper.threadedregions.EntityScheduler.executeTick(EntityScheduler.java:173) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.tickServer(MinecraftServer.java:1646) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at io.papermc.paper.threadedregions.TickRegions$ConcreteRegionTickHandle.tickRegion(TickRegions.java:407) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at io.papermc.paper.threadedregions.TickRegionScheduler$RegionScheduleHandle.runTick(TickRegionScheduler.java:404) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at ca.spottedleaf.concurrentutil.scheduler.SchedulerThreadPool$TickThreadRunner.run(SchedulerThreadPool.java:525) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R3.CraftServer.createWorld(CraftServer.java:1286) ~[folia-1.20.4.jar:git-Folia-"ec6b172"]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.createWorld(Bukkit.java:835) ~[folia-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.WorldCreator.createWorld(WorldCreator.java:502) ~[folia-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.pluralistic.Pluralistic.onCommand(Pluralistic.java:57) ~[Pluralistic-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[folia-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        ... 20 more


UnsupportedOperationException with Folia means you are not using it in the right scheduler.
On Folia, lot of actions should be run on specific scheduler. The use case is:

GlobalRegionScheduler for all world-related content but not about a specific region
RegionScheduler for everything related to a specific part of the world (a block, a chunk etc)
EntityScheduler for everything which is entity-related
AsyncScheduler for all async tasks

In your case, you want to load/save the world. It's world-related (read the world content), but not about a specific region. So, you should use GlobalRegionScheduler. You can get it thanks to Bukkit.getGlobalRegionScheduler()
If, for example, you want to do async tasks, you can firstly do an async task, then only when you need, "go" on the global region scheduler to do what you want.
Note: In your specific case, the Bukkit.createWorld(WorldCreator); method seems not allowed on folia. You should use others Bukkit.createWorld(String name, Environment env etc), or simply use worldCreator.createWorld().

I've already tried GlobalRegionScheduler, but it didn't have any effect, so I'm unsure if WorldCreate needs to use the scheduler.

@PlaidMrdeer sorry for the time, and yes you should also use worldCreator.createWorld() instead of Bukkit.createWorld
